# Can't find nor install mysql_config

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I get this error from Inspircd

```
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at /home/alpha/inspircd-2.0.19/make/utilities.pm line 392, <FLAGS> line 37.


Make sure you have pkg-config installed

In the case of gnutls configuration errors on debian,
Ubuntu, etc, you should ensure that you have installed
gnutls-bin as well as libgnutls-dev and libgnutls.
```

I've been looking all over the internet trying to find out how to remove the errors.

I have read multiple threads but no luck. I know I need the libmysqlclient-dev package but I can't for the life of me get it installed.

I run

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Also tried cleaning, "-f" and so on but I still get the error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.40-0ubuntu1) but 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried it with aptitude

```
sudo aptitude install libmysqlclient-dev
```

then I downgraded libmysqlclient18 one version and now it works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

you tried remove all PPA ( Personal Package Archive )?

before try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install libmysqlclient-dev
```

I see in Bugtrack MYSQL:

https://goo.gl/34NUgo

your ERROR is Bug know **Bug #73522     Installation of libmysqlclient-dev fails if libmysqlclient18 is from percona**

still unsolved:

> status: **Unsupported**

environment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; Kernel 3.13, MySql 5.6

att

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tu upgrade your `libmysqlclient18` packet ? (Perform an `apt-get update` before, just in case ...)

Comment: I'm not so used to Ubuntu yet. Could you maybe explain it pretty much step by step of how I upgrade libmysqlclient18? apt-get upgrade?

Comment: The easiest way would be to upgrade all your package.
`apt-get update` (in order to get the list of last package)
`apt-get upgrade` (in order to install up to date packages)
A list of "need to be updated" packages will be shown, if you want to upgrade all of them, jsut press "yes"
If you just want to upgrade "libmysqlclient18" package :
`apt-get install --only-upgrade libmysqlclient18`. But maybe "libmysqlclient-dev" will need other upgrade... That's why I'm suggesting you the easier way.

Comment: this is what I got "Calculating upgrade... The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libopenvg1-mesa-lts-utopic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
"